# Having trouble understanding pointer operations

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence, unary-operator, postfix-operator

I can't exactly understand what the language does when I write

```
*(t++)

*t++
```

When `t` is a pointer?

Comment: I could be wrong, but those two forms should have the exact same behavior.

Comment: https://ideone.com/YJtPWL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two expressions

```
*(t++)

*t++
```

are equivalent due to the operator precedence.

So the postfix operator ++ has a higher priority than the unary operator *.

The result of the postfix operator ++ is the value of its operand before incrementing.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand**.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)....

Take into account that due to the pointer arithmetic if you have a pointer like this

```
T *p;
```

where `T` is some type then after the operation `p++` the final value of the pointer itself is incremented by the value `sizeof( T )`.  For the type `char sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *t = "AB";

    printf( "%c\n", *t++ );
    printf( "%c\n", *t );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A
B
```

You can substitute this statement

```
printf( "%c\n", *t++ );
```

for this statement

```
printf( "%c\n", *( t++ ) );
```

and you will get the same result.

In fact this expression

```
*(t++)
```

is also equivalent to the expression

```
t++[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions are equivalent.

The postfix increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  As a result `*(t++)` and `*t++` do the same thing.  Namely, the pointer `t` is incremented, and the original value of `t` prior to incremented is dereferenced.